# Using media query to append "•" after <li>, only when item is not last in line

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm new to responsive web design and I guess that this should be pretty simple but I can't find a solution.

I have a (Right to Left) responsive webpage. It has footer links, and they look like that:
[image: Footer]

At the moment, I'm adding a `.no-bullet` class to the last `<li>` element, and using CSS to add a bullet to the all of the items except that last one:

```
li.list-item-footer:not(.no-bullet):after{
    content: "•";
    color: #611aa8;
}
```

Problem is - it has to be responsive. On smaller screen it may look like that:

[image: Galaxy S5]

(On this example, i'd expect the bullet on the left of 55555 to disappear)

I assume that this could be archivied with media query, but I can't find the solution online.

This is the template (Angular 4):

```
<ul class="list-inline list-footer d-inline-block pt-4">

  <!-- pulls all footer links from config.json file-->
  <ng-container *ngFor="let link of appService.config?.footer">
    <li [ngClass]="{'list-inline-item list-item-footer' : true, 'no-bullet': !link.showbullet}">
      <a [href]="link.link" class="link-footer no-text-decoration" [target]="link.target">{{link.display}}</a>
    </li>
  </ng-container>

</ul>
```

Comment: can you share the minimal code that shows this without angular part and with  the relevant CSS

Comment: Are your `<li>` elements float left ?

Comment: edited my answer and use float left on li elements.

Answer (score 0):

I made a really basic snippet to achieve your desired effect. Having the elements float left will automatically put them into the new line, if they exceed the boundaries of their parent. If you resize `body` in the example you will see the effect. Futhermore, using the `before` - selector you can add `content` infront of the element. You also can use `:not(:first-child)` to affect every element of your selection but the first one.

```css
ul
{
  list-style-type: none
}

ul li
{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

ul li:not(:first-child):before
{
  content: "•  ";
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul>
<li>55555</li>
<li>66666666</li>
<li>777777</li>
<li>888888888</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have the bullet :before the text on new lines. I want it neither on start of lines nor end of lines. Actually, maybe the fact I used <li> in that occasion was wrong... Because the bullet is not a list style type, but an item separator, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick to remove the first dot by using `ul:before` with `position:absolute` on responsive version using media query

...the idea is here to create a fake div with same background-color as `ul` to overlap the first dot.

*<sup>Note: You will need to adjust the width of `ul:before` according to your screen size</sup>*

***Stack Snippet***

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  background: maroon;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  direction: rtl;
  color: #fff;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:after {
  content: "•";
  position: absolute;
  left: -22px;
}

ul li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  ul:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    background: #800400;
    content: "";
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>11111</li>
  <li>22222</li>
  <li>33333</li>
  <li>44444</li>
  <li>55555</li>
  <li>66666</li>
  <li>77777</li>
</ul>
```

**[Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/8uc8v9mk/1/)**